# Dual boot, raid 0 and 2 identical hdds

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, 20.04, raid

I have a dual boot win10/ubuntu, 2 hdd's in raid 0 and i'm trying to use 2 TB on windows and 2 TB on ubuntu.
I gave windows he's 2 tbs but I can't figure out which one is the not allocated in ubuntu.

How do I do that?

This is disk manager in windows https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bl2A.jpg

When I open gparted it gave me those errors/views https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lGoE.jpg

The first 2 pics are errors that I always get when launching the program, the other 3 pics are of the view for the ssd (main disk, also divided in w10 and ubuntu) and the 2 partitions of the hdds.

As you can see it thinks that both partitions of the hdds are unallocated, why does it? How do I find which one is not?

The first error (also first pic) says (i guess) that there was an error reading "sdb", could it be because it's of windows? or is it because it's the unallocated one?

Comment: What is the raid? Is it intel RST?

Comment: I don't really know but i guess it's not, I did it from bios etc etc (I have a MSI H270 PC MATE mobo, if that can help)

Comment: It looks like you converted UEFI/gpt system to have a Windows install in the now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since Windows 8 released in 2012, so newer hardware is UEFI. Windows incorrectly converts gpt to MBR leaving backup gpt partition table. If you really want only BIOS you have to delete backup gpt. to remove backup gpt: http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/ But much better to reinstall Wiindows in UEFI boot mode.